# How to use the compute function in dart to pass more than one parameter?

Tags: flutter

I need to use isolate to compute a rather heavy calculation for the app im developing.

All i managed to find is how to pass a single to compute function

but i need to pass more than 1 param to the function, can anyone tell me the synthax

```
 compute(function,param);
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075492/10515117)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send multiple arguments to the compute function in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54074857/send-multiple-arguments-to-the-compute-function-in-flutter)